# multi level query in sql

Tags: mysql

I want a query on 3 tables which will give me a result like below:

I've `USERID` depending on this I want to fetch the data from the table below:

`ANSTABLE`

```
 ID | ANS | USERID | QUERYID
  1 | 123 |   1    | 15
  2 | 22  |   0    | 16
  3 | 17  |   1    | 10
```

ID from ANSTABLE is mapped with ANSID in ANSVOTABLE

`ANSVOTABLE`

```
 USERID | QUERYID | ANSID | UPVOTE | DOWNVOTE
    3   |    15   |   1   |   1    |    0 
    8   |    15   |   1   |   0    |   -1 
    7   |    15   |   1   |   0    |   -1
    22  |    16   |   2   |   1    |    0
```

QUERYID id mapped with ID from 'QUERYTABLE'

`QUERYTABLE`

```
 ID | USERID | QUERY   | DESCRIPTION
 16 |  10    | qwerty  | uytrew
 15 |  11    | my_data | test_data
 10 |  0     | 101010  | 101010
```

Now I want a result like, whenever I give USERID - 0 OR 1 etc.
it should fetch all queryID's related to entered USERID from `ANSTABLE`
and depending on matched queryID's all records should be returned from `QUERYTABLE` table and also it should give me `SUM(UPVOTE)+SUM(DOWNVOTE) as total` corresponding to ANSID && QUERYID from `ANSVOTABLE`.

In fact i want result like below
if i enter `userID - 1 it should give me by adding one more column

```
 ID | USERID | QUERY   | DESCRIPTION | ANSSCORE
 15 |  11    | my_data | test_data   |   -1
 10 |  0     | 101010  | 101010      |    0
```

Please note that ANSSCORE becomes `-1` from the result of `ANSVOTABLE` by calculating upvote and downvote.

Also consider if corresponding AnsID and QueryId is not existing in `ANSVOTABLE` then in that case it should return me record from Querytable with o as total score

Answers will be appriciated.

Comment: Why are mysql and oracle both tagged.. Both databases work different..

Comment: I dont understand why/who the second record is included in the resultset..UserID 11 - 1 is not UserID 0 i more expect UserID 10 there as second record..

Comment: Your Result is not matching with your question expectation  ? please correct your output / question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `join` those 3 tables on the `keys` and then do a 2 or 3rd-degree `group by` with whatever `where clause` you have as requirement.

I think this might work for you -

```
SELECT q.ID, q.QUERY, q.USERID, vote.UPVOTE + vote.DOWNVOTE as totalVote 
FROM QUERYTABLE q
JOIN ANSTABLE ans ON ans.QUERYID = q.ID
JOIN ANSVOTABLE vote ON vote.ANSID = ans.ID
WHERE ans.USERID = 2
GROUP BY q.ID, q.QUERY, q.USERID;
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but i'm not getting `10 |  0     | 101010  | 101010      |    0 ` this record if that queryId and ansId does not exists in `ANSVOTABLE`. In that case it should give me totalscore as 0.

Comment: `.. LEFT JOIN ANSVOTABLE vote ON vote.ANSID = ans.ID` this worked for me for this condition

Answer (score 1):

You just need to sum the two columns and group by the other columns you want. You've already defined the table relationships so this should be fairly straightforward unless I'm misunderstanding something.

```
create table anstable(
ID number,
ANS number,
USERID number,
QUERYID number);

Insert into anstable values(1, 123, 1, 15);
Insert into anstable values(2, 22, 0, 16);
Insert into anstable values(3, 17, 1, 10);

create table ANSVOTABLE(
USERID number,
QUERYID number,
ANSID number,
UPVOTE number,
DOWNVOTE number);

Insert into ansvotable values(3, 15, 1, 1, 0);
Insert into ansvotable values(8, 15, 1, 0, -1);
Insert into ansvotable values(7, 15, 1, 0, -1);
Insert into ansvotable values(22, 16, 2, 1, 0); 

create table QUERYTABLE(
ID number,
USERID number,
QUERY varchar2(50),
DESCRIPTION varchar2(50));

insert into querytable values(16, 10, 'qwerty', 'uytrew');
insert into querytable values(15,  11, 'my_data', 'test_data');
insert into querytable values(10,  0, '101010', '101010');

select a.id, a.userid, a.query, a.description, sum(b.upvote + b.downvote) as ansscore
from querytable a
join ansvotable b on b.queryid = a.id
join anstable c on c.id = b.ansid
where c.userid in (0, 1)
group by a.id, a.userid, a.query, a.description;
```

Results:

```
Table created.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

Table created.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

Table created.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

Result Set 1
ID  USERID  QUERY   DESCRIPTION ANSSCORE
15  11  my_data test_data   -1
16  10  qwerty  uytrew  1
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but i'm not getting 10 | 0 | 101010 | 101010 | 0 this record if that queryId and ansId does not exists in ANSVOTABLE. In that case it should give me totalscore as 0.

Comment: That requirement was not in your original question. In that case you would need a LEFT JOIN on ANSVOTABLE instead.